# Copy/Paste list workflow 2013's IF statement from one workflow to another will change all the "ORs" to "ANDs"

Tags: workflow, 2016, workflow-manager, workflow2013, list-workflow

I have created a new list workflow 2013 inside my SharePoint 2013. Now the list workflow has the following IF statement with multiple conditions with OR applied between them, as follow:-

[image]

now I created another empty list workflow inside another list then I copy the above If statement and paste it inside the new workflow. now I have noted that all the "or" were changed to "and" on the posted IF statement. now I know that I can change the "and" back to "or".. but not sure if any other settings have changed also ?? as I know copy/paste workflows stages and conditions should work .. but not sure what caused this problem??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why it happens, but can tell you you're not alone. You'll always need to reapply the actions/conditions and anything you've got in, say, emails that call up data.

Comment: so i need to re-check my pasted conditions for any missing settings ??

Comment: Yes, I'd say definitely, even if they look ok. I'm sure the values copied should work, but once bitten...